# how to make an editText not editable in code

Tags: android, kotlin

how to make an editText not editable and how to make it editable again I want the solution in kotlin code
I tried (editText.isFocusable = false) it works but when i want it editable again (editText.isFocusable = true) does not make it editable again

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that one because that one is about XML, and this one is about changing it in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that

```
yourEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried (`isFocusableInTouchMode = true`) it does make the `EditText` editable again. And I use `isFocusable = false` when I want it not editable